# Read (and write) RTF files with C++ / Qt

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, rtf

I am looking for a simple C++ library for tokenizing and parsing RTF (Rich Text Format) files. I am planning to edit them with Qt's QTextEdit.

More the Formatting preserved the better -- but actually I am planning to use Bold and Italics only.

In perl I would use [RTF::Tokenizer](http://search.cpan.org/%7Esargie/RTF-Tokenizer-1.10/lib/RTF/Tokenizer.pm).

It would be nice if the module had some sort of interface for writing also, but I am able to brute force that with a template and some regular expressions.

Comment: did you ever find a working answer?

Answer (score 11):

I helped writing the RTF import export filter in KOffice. You can have a look at the code at https://cgit.kde.org/koffice.git/tree/filters/kword/rtf. The code is modular and it depends only on Qt.

Comment: This link seems to be broken.

Comment: This one seems to work: https://projects.kde.org/projects/unmaintained/koffice/repository/revisions/master/show/filters/kword/rtf

Answer (score 6):

A quick SourceForge search suggests [librtf](http://www.sf.net/projects/librtf). It hasn't been developed in a while, but is listed as stable and is under the LGPL. I don't know whether it will support what you need, but I always suggest searching SourceForge for libraries.

Comment: Well RTF hasn't seen a  development either, so maybe it's just feature complete like libjpeg or libpng.  Microsoft who once created for office document exchange officially put it to rest 10 years ago with office 2007 in favour of the open office xml format.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the `#koffice` guys on `irc.freenode.org` over irc. Their program `kword` is able to open RTF files, and is indeed also written in Qt. I'm sure they would be glad to tell you about how they do it.